# J-Language Functions similar to the Anagram Index (A.)

Tags: permutation, combinatorics, j

Are there really simple ways to accomplish something similar to the Anagram Index (`A.`) functions on an "n choose k" permutation in J?

So, I love `A.` in J. Just to show that I understand it slightly:

```
   A. 0 3 4 2 1
17
   17 A. i.5
0 3 4 2 1
```

I also know that I can use it to permute a list (`17 A. things`) or use the results to select from a list, if that's any different (`(17 A. i.5) { things`).

I'm looking for a function that will produce a number similar to `A.` and also do the inverse to recreate the selection for the "n choose k" permutations, both with and without replacement. Order does matter to me, so `0 2 7` is different than `7 0 2`, but I'd be interested in versions that don't care about order (such as when rolling dice in Yahtzee).

I'm prepared to start figuring this out on my own and writing my own function, but I just have to assume that this is a solved problem, especially in a language like J that includes `A.` as a primitive.

Just to be clear, by "n choose k," I'm talking about rolling dice ("6 choose 3, with replacement" for rolling 3 dice, one after another) and horse race winners ("20 choose 3, without replacement" for the top 3 horses in a 20-horse race).

Comment: As a side note: I have trouble using Google to search for info about J. Any tips besides including "J language" in my query?

Comment: If you are looking specifically for information from the jsoftware.com site using google you can use 'site:jsoftware.com' to prefix the search term. The other option for a lot of information is the wiki at the Jsoftware.com site. Otherwise searching 'J' on the wider web is a bit problematic. :)

Comment: Exactly. The majority of what I've found so far has been at jsoftware.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "6 choose 3, with replacement", you can use [catalog `{`](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d520.htm):

```
{3#<i.6
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 2│0 0 3│0 0 4│0 0 5│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 2│0 1 3│0 1 4│0 1 5│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
...
```

You can take the reverse as the index of the above matrix (unraveled), feg:

```
(0 0 0) I.~ >,{3#<i.6
0
(0 1 0) I.~ >,{3#<i.6
6
(5 5 5) I.~ >,{3#<i.6
215
(4 5 1) I.~ >,{3#<i.6
175

175 { >,{3#<i.6
4 5 1
```

There are some relevant essays on combinations on jsoftware.com: [Combination Index](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Combination%20Index), [Combinations](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Combinations) and others.

Comment: I've played with what you've written and I believe that I've understood it. I also realized that `A. 0 1 3` gives me a usable anagram index for a partial permutation (my horse race). I can also rebuild the permutation with `_3 {. (12 A. i.4)` but I feel like there has to be a cleaner way to rebuild that permutation than `buildthree =: 3 : '_3 {. (y A. i.(>. (!inv y)))'`.

Comment: The linked pages are excellent and the `comb` functions look like they'll do what I need. I guess those essays prove that there isn't a primitive or pair of primitives that do what I need.